# For loop final output

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

Not sure where I am going wrong, but I want the final output to only show any lines hat do not contain C:\Windows\System OR C:\Windows\system32

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%n in ('sc query state^= all ^| findstr SERVICE_NAME') do (
  for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%r in (
    'sc qc "%%~n" ^| findstr BINARY_PATH_NAME'
  ) do (
    echo %%~s ^| findstr /V "C:\Windows\system32 C:\Windows\System32"
  )
)
```

The output just lists all the commands in the loop but does not provide my my final list of services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
echo %%~s ^| findstr /V "C:\Windows\system32 C:\Windows\System32"
```

to

```
echo %%~s | findstr /V /I "c:\windows\system32"
```

In other words, add a case-insensitive flag, and remove the escaping of the pipe character. This works for me if I save it as a `.cmd` file.